# How to configure sonarqube for code coverage?

Tags: maven, module, sonarqube, code-coverage

At the moment I can get sonarqube to scan some files using mvn sonar:sonar, but I can never get the code coverage. I have looked through all the docs and included jacoco in my poms and tried to set the project-properties to reflect the structure of the code. I have not really used maven before so this task is a bit hard. Can someone supply me with an "explain it like I'm five" solution for me. I have multiple modules as well.

Answer (score 2):

codecoverage is not a job of sonarqube. Sonarqube can read codecoverage analyse from jacoco and cobertura. So begin with configure your projet in order to work with jacoco/cobertura in the maven way and, you should see the html report in target/site after code coverage analyse.
Then, after all you can do sonar:sonar and a report should appear on sonarqube dashboard project.